# Using chi-squared test to compare distributions in R

Tags: r, categorical-data, chi-squared-test

I have a factor variable with two levels that represent a patient's baseline condition. I have separated these patients into two groups based on another variable - these two groups do not have the same number of patients in them.

Using a chi-squared test, I want to compare the distribution of this baseline condition between the two groups of patients.

How would this be done in R?

Comment: It sounds like you have four groups, not two. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @Dave group 1: major operation or light procedure, group 2: major operation or light procedure; I want to see what the difference in distribution is for the two groups

Comment: @Dave but whether a patient had a major operation or a light procedure is stored in one variable (called baseline)

Comment: `?chisq.test` ..

Answer (score 1):

To test for the presence of association between two factors through the associated contingency table, you have a bunch of possibilities, below are two of the most popular options:

1. If the sample size is small it is advisable to use [Fisher's exact test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test) which provides an exact $p$-value. It is implemented in the `R` command `fisher.test`
2. With large samples you may use a [chi-squared test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test) or the [G-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-test). The $p$-values provided by these tests are approximate since the sampling distribution of the test statistic is a chi-squared only in the limit as the sample size goes to infinity. The approximation is particularly inadequate when sample sizes are small, or the expected counts under the null hypothesis are very low. As suggested by @Glen_b, you can run the chi-squared test in `R` by the command `chisq.test`; implementation of the G-test is provided by the command `g.test` in the `ARM` package.